# Interleaving IDs of groups, with IDs coming from 2 separate arrays, defining size of groups

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, grouping

1. **The problem**

I have 2 different functions, named `update()` and `reset()`.
I am referring to these functions as 'IDs' in the title of the ticket.
They apply successively to groups of contiguous rows from a `data` array.

The sizes of groups to which apply these functions are defined in related arrays.

```py
import numpy as np

# 'data' array, size 5.
data = np.array([1., 4., 3., 8., 9.], dtype='float64')

# Group sizes to which will apply 'update' function.
update_gs = np.array([1, 0, 2, 2], dtype='int64')
# Sum of group sizes is 5, the number of rows in `data`.
# This array means that the 'update' function is to be performed successively on:
# - the 1st row
# - then without any row from data
# - then with the 2nd and 3rd rows from data
# - then with the 4th and 5th rows from data

# Group sizes to which will apply 'reset' function.
reset_gs = np.array([2, 0, 0, 2, 1], dtype='int64')
# Sum of group sizes is 5, the number of rows in `data`.
# This array means that the 'reset' function is to be performed successively on:
# - the 2 1st rows
# - a 2nd and 3rd reset will be run without any row from data
# - a 4th reset will be run with 3rd and 4th rows from data
# - a 5th reset will be run with the last row from data
```

The result I am looking for from this input data are 2 1D arrays:

- each row of these result arrays relates to one occurrence of either `update` or `reset`.
- consequently, these arrays are of size `len(update_gs) + len(reset_gs)`, i.e. here 8
- one array is of `int`, defining group sizes again. In this result array, group sizes are defined as the number of the 'elapsed' rows since the previous occurrence of `update` or `reset`.
- the other array is of `bool`, defining if a row relates to a `reset` function (value `True`) or an `update` function (value `False`)
- regarding the order of appearance of the `update` and `reset` occurrences:

  - row groups in `data` of `update` and `reset` occurrences overlap. Considering the last rows in their respective row groups, the row coming the latter between each row group makes also the corresponding occurrence (`update` and `reset`) the latter.
  - When row groups of an `update` and a `reset` occurrence share the same last row, then `update` comes 1st in result array.

With previous data, expected results are:

```py
group_sizes = np.array([1, # 1st action is 'update'. It applies to 1st row in data.
                        0, # There is a 2nd 'update' on 0 row.
                        1, # At 2nd row of data, there is the 1st 'reset' action.
                        0, # There is a 2nd 'reset' on 0 row.
                        0, # There is a 3rd 'reset' on 0 row.
                        1, # There is the 3rd 'update' taking place, with 1 row elapsed since previous function.
                        1, # There is a 4th 'reset', with 1 row elapsed since previous function.
                        1, # There is the 4th 'update' taking place, with 1 row elapsed since previous function.
                        0, # Occurs finally the last 'reset', with same ending row in 'data' than the previous 'update'
                       ], dtype='int64')
# Sum of the values gives 5, the total number of rows in 'data'.                        

function_ids = np.array([False, # 1st action is 'update'.
                         False, # There is a 2nd 'update'.
                         True,  # There is the 1st 'reset' action.
                         True,  # There is a 2nd 'reset'.
                         True,  # There is a 3rd 'reset'.
                         False, # There is the 3rd 'update'.
                         True,  # There is a 4th 'reset'.
                         False, # There is the 3rd 'update'.
                         True,  # Occurs finally the last 'reset'.
                        ], dtype='bool')
```

2. **Possibly a XY problem?**

Above question is raised considering following topic:

- I have as inputs the 2 arrays mentioned, `reset_gs` and `update_gs`. The way the related functions (`update` or `reset`) work depends what function has been applied on the previous group (a `reset` or an `update`?) and its result.
- For this reason, I tried 1st to interleave the respective calls in 2 `for` loops, imbricated. This results in a complex code, that I have not been successful at making work yet. I believe after some time, it might be possible, with several `if`s, buffer variables and boolean flags to communicate about previous states between the 2 interleaved `for` loops. In terms of maintenance / simplicity of code, it really does not seem adequate.
- For this reason, I believe that opting to a flatten `for` loop is preferable. The 2 resulting arrays I am looking for (above question) will enable me to opt for such a solution.

3. **What about looping over `data`?**

Size of `data` is several millions of rows.
Size of `update_gs` is several thousands of rows.
Size of `reset_gs` varies from several hundreds to several thousands of rows.

Looking for performance, I have reasons to believe that looping over `update_gs` & `reset_gs` (i.e. group definitions - several thousand iterations) instead of `data` (each row individually - several millions iterations) will result in faster code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned into 'how making a mergesort?'.
I discovered about [sortednp](https://gitlab.sauerburger.com/frank/sortednp) package in the way, that seems the fast way to do it.

```py
import numpy as np
from sortednp import merge # merge of sorted numpy arrays

# Input data.
update = np.array([1, 0, 2, 2], dtype='int64')
reset = np.array([2, 0, 0, 2, 1], dtype='int64')

# Switching from group sizes to indices of group last row, in-place.
np.cumsum(update, out=update)
np.cumsum(reset, out=reset)
# Performing a merge of sorted arrays, keeping insertion index for 'update'.
merged_idx, (update_idx, _) = merge(update, reset, indices=True)
# Going back to group sizes.
merged_gs = np.diff(merged_idx, prepend=0)
# Final step to get 'function_ids'.
function_ids = np.ones(len(merged_gs), dtype="bool")
function_ids[update_idx] = False

# Here we are.
merged_gs
Out[9]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
function_ids
Out[13]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True])
```